# SVGs not showing in FireFox or Safari / Django / Angular - Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, svg

We have a Django / Angular 1.5 app running on Heroku. We've used SVG icon sprites in this format:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

  <symbol id="icon-brand" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="m475 256c0 40-9 77-29 110c-20 34-46 60-80 80c-33 20-70 29-110 29c-40 0-77-9-110-29c-34-20-60-46-80-80c-20-33-29-70-29-110c0-40 9-77 29-110c20-34 46-60 80-80c33-20 70-29 110-29c40 0 77 9 110 29c34 20 60 46 80 80c20 33 29 70 29 110z"/>
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

to load them in the body,
and then

```
<svg class='icon-x'><use xlink:href="#icon-brand"></use></svg>
```

to use them in the markup.

(from [fontastic](http://fontastic.me/))

[Here is an example of the SVG code we use on codepen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/EdCDr). There is a version that uses a Angular directive and another standard syntax. This example works on FireFox and Safari, but our live app isn't showing it's SVGs.

*Because it works on CodePen*, I think it's an issue of either cross-origin or something like .htaccess on our server, but Django uses [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) fot it's server. I've used snippets for .htaccess in many PHP sites before but the way things need to be setup have differed with each host/server setup.
I would like to know exactly what is happening and if the SVGs are being read as XML or if we need to send a special header so that I can put a better plan in place for future projects with this setup.

Does anyone have experience ensuring their SVGs have a clear path in this setting?

It seems like a path issue and not a server issue.

http://www.chriskrycho.com/2015/html5-location-base-and-svg.html

[Angular $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

[Angular $location/nobase](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

We've put this fix in place but there seems to be no support in IE9 for HTML5 mode.

Comment: Could be you're serving files with the wrong mime type or that you're putting a `<base>` element into the page via angular. Either would likely break things.

Comment: There is a `<base '/'>` element in there. It definitely seems like a path issue and not a server issue.